# vue3 nested search filter

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

Please help to return filteredList() based on comparing for similarity input search with key 'info': array.

It always says its undefined.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      postList: [
        {
          title: "hello",
          info: ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
        },
        {
          title: "goodbye",
          info: ["five", "six"],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.postList.filter((item) => {
        return item.info.includes(this.search);
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach ?

Comment: It does return empty array. Even if search input is empty.

Comment: `item.info.includes(this.search)` will return true only if the search term is in the array. What's your searching criteria ?

Comment: Right... How to make filter , same as its filters item.title.includes(this.search) , even when one symbol is similar?  And when search input is empty, is returns unfiltered array. ...

Comment: Change your filter condition to  `item.info.some(s => s.includes(this.search))`